# Convert a large list of timestamps in an excel file from one format to another with python

Tags: python, excel, timestamp

I have an excel file named "hello123.xlsx". There is a column of timestamps that has a lot of rows (more than 80,000 rows for now). The excel file basically looks like this:

```
Tue Mar 13 14:51:04 +0000 2018

Tue Mar 13 14:51:10 +0000 2018

Tue Mar 13 14:51:11 +0000 2018

Tue Mar 13 14:51:12 +0000 2018

Tue Mar 13 14:51:13 +0000 2018

Tue Mar 13 14:51:13 +0000 2018

Tue Mar 13 14:51:15 +0000 2018

Tue Mar 13 14:51:35 +0000 2018

Tue Mar 13 14:51:43 +0000 2018

Tue Mar 13 14:52:12 +0000 2018
```

And so on...

As can be seen above, the timestamps I have is in the format of this:

%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y.

But I need to convert it to the standard format like %m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.

So basically I have to read a column of numerous timestamps in an excel file and then to convert them to a new format in a new column.

I'm very new to python and I searched some methods online but failed to do so. I hope someone can help figure it out I would really appreciate that.  :)

Comment: Post a sample of your dataset as text, not as an image.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stack overflow. What have you tried? You may want to read the docs on `datetime.strftime()` and `datetime.strptime()` here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Hi aylr, thank you for your response. Do you know how to do both reading the excel file and converting timestamps format within it?  I'm the very beginner of python, it would be very helpful if you can help me with that. Thanks!  @aylr

Comment: Hi Chrisz, coulod you please post your answer again? I can't find it now. Thanks!  @chrisz

Comment: @liule123 I incorrectly read csv, instead of xlsx, I updated and undeleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this quite easily using the [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library, in particular [`pandas.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

You will also need to install [`xlrd`](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd) and [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('in.xlsx', header=None)

df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0]).dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

df.to_excel('out.xlsx', index=False, header=False)
```

Sample run:

> in.xlsx

```
Tue Mar 13 14:51:04 +0000 2018
Tue Mar 13 14:51:04 +0000 2018
Tue Mar 13 14:51:04 +0000 2018
Tue Mar 13 14:51:04 +0000 2018
```

> out.xlsx

```
03/13/2018 14:51:04
03/13/2018 14:51:04
03/13/2018 14:51:04
03/13/2018 14:51:04
```

Comment: Hi chrisz, I tried that and it works!!!   But there is a problem that in the output file, seconds (%S) are actually missed out. So an output sample looks like this: 3/13/2018 14:51.    Do you know how to solve it?   @chrisz

Comment: Try printing the dataframe after you run the second line (the one that uses `to_datetime`), and make sure it is including seconds there.  Also verify that the time format is `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S`

Comment: Hi chrisz, actually I made a mistake that I had .csv instead of .xlsx for my output file. I fixed it and now it works. Thank you very much!  @chrisz

Comment: Glad to help, happy programming!

Comment: Hi chrisz, now I want to convert these timestamps from UTC time to US/Pacific time (UTC, -7). I searched some methods online and tried some formula function within excel but failed to make it right. I guess I need to write some codes in python. It would be very helpful if you could give some suggestions.  ~   @chrisz

Answer (score 0):

Use `strptime()` to convert the string into a datetime object and then use `strftime()` to format that object into the string you desire. See https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

[Openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) can be used to read and write *.xlsx files.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can transform timestamp in excel with something like this:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),IF(MID(A1,5,3)="Jan",1,IF(MID(A1,5,3)="Feb",2,IF(MID(A1,5,3)="Mar",3,IF(MID(A1,5,3)="Apr",4,
IF(MID(A1,5,3)="May",5,IF(MID(A1,5,3)="Jun",6,IF(MID(A1,5,3)="Jul",7,IF(MID(A1,5,3)="Aug",8,IF(MID(A1,5,3)="Sep",9,IF(MID(A1,5,3)="Okt",10,IF(MID(A1,5,3)="Nov",11,IF(MID(A1,5,3)="Dec",12,0)))))))))))),MID(A1,9,2)) + (MID(A1,12,8))
```

In A1 is timestamp ex. Tue Mar 13 14:51:04 +0000 2018